# logrotate by size - do I need to change the cron?

Tags: cron, logrotate

My current logrotate configuration looks like this (using logrotate 3.8.7)

```
"/var/log/haproxy.log" {
  daily
  size 250M
  rotate 1
  create 644 root root
  missingok
  compress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

It successfully runs once a day, but when size exceeds 250M it doesn't get rotated. So it waits until the end of the day to rotate, regardless of size.

I've read that there is the maxsize option, and after changing `size 250M` to `maxsize 250M` it still doesn't work.

Do I need to set a cron to run logrotate in an hourly manner, or logrotate gets run automatically because is listening to that file size, and I have something else wrong going on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you need to run `logrotate` more than once a day to achieve this. This is answered in the seconds paragraph of the man page [`logrotate`(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate):

> Normally, `logrotate` is run as a daily cron job. It will not modify a
>   log multiple times in one day unless the criterion for that log is
>   based on the log's size and `logrotate` is being run multiple times each
>   day, or unless the `-f` or `--force` option is used.

If you would like to run `logrotate` hourly instead of daily, you can move it:

```
mv /etc/cron.daily/logrotate /etc/cron.hourly
```

Since 3.8.1 there has been `maxsize`. The difference between `size` and `maxsize` is described here:

> `maxsize` size
>
> Log files are rotated when they grow bigger than size bytes even
>      before  the additionally specified time interval (`daily`, `weekly`,
>      `monthly`, or `yearly`).  The related `size` option is similar  except
>      that  it  is  mutually exclusive with the time interval options,
>      and it causes log files to be rotated  without  regard  for  the
>      last  rotation  time.   When  `maxsize` is used, both the size and
>      timestamp of a log file are considered.

This would make both suitable for your use: `size` without any interval and `maxsize` if also interval is needed. However, this doesn't change the fact that by default `logrotate` runs only daily. That interval is suitable for most, as in most cases it takes a lot longer than a day for a log to grow over `250M`.

Comment: FYI there is a maxsize directive, starting from 8.1: ftp://hpux.connect.org.uk/hpux/Sysadmin/logrotate-3.8.7/logrotate-3.8.7.man.html

Comment: Thanks for noticing I was reading an ancient version of the manual, @HommerSmith! I corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that the `logrotate` `cron` script originally found in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` may contain the following lines: `# skip in favour of systemd timer`, `if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then`, `exit 0`, `fi`. If it does, and `/run/systemd/system` is a directory on your system, then you need to comment out/delete those lines, otherwise moving `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` to `/etc/cron.hourly` isn't going to make any difference. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465677/8477566) for more information